# Why different noise terms are read at specific sampling interval in Allan Variance plot?

Tags: imu, calibration, accelerometer, noise, gyro

I was trying to identify Quantization Noise, Angle Random Walk, Bias Instability, and Rate Random Walk from Allan Variance plot which as Allan deviation on y axis and Sampling Time Interval `T` on x axis. Several sources [[1](https://in.mathworks.com/help/nav/ug/inertial-sensor-noise-analysis-using-allan-variance.html)][[2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/660628)] say that we can read these values directly from the plot when `T=3^1/2, T=1, Slope=0, T=3` respectively. I am trying to understand why is this the case.

Here is my understanding: Allan Variance (AVAR) plot is generated by calculating AVAR at different sampling intervals `T`. Different noise processes have different slopes and they appear in different regions of `T`. Now, **"its empirical observation" (and there is no mathematical proof as such)** that Allan Variance plot is sensitive to different noise process at different sampling intervals `T`. For example, Allan Variance plot is sensitive to random walk component at T=3, while sensitive to white noise component for `T=1`. Thats why we simply read y axis deviation values for these different x axis T values to obtain corresponding values for these different noise processes.

Am I correct with this? That is this mapping of noise processes to different values of T is purely based on empirical observation of how these noises appear in sensors?